# brute force ssh account with key-pair authentication?

Tags: ssh, brute-force

Recently one of my servers has been hacked and it seems they got SSH access (logs are removed, ransom readme files created etc..). The account has a ssh certificate authentication (incl. passphrase for the private key) and I wonder if:

1. there's any real chance for an attacker to brute force certificate based accounts via ssh?
2. or the greater chance is, that they even got a trojan on my local computer and got the key file incl. the passphrase?

Comment: Can you clarify 2, do you use a password vault and you worry they stole the file and passphrase?

Comment: No, I dont use password vault, I always type in the password via keyboard whenever I need to unlock the private key.

Comment: Are you sure root login is disabled and password authentication is disabled in your sshd_config?

Comment: Good point - both PasswordAuthentication & PermitRootLogin are set to yes in SSHD config. But when I try to directly ssh via `ssh root@<ip>` I get the error `Permission denied (publickey).`. That should work then, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute forcing the certificate is very unlikely. More likely are:

- Virus/trojan extracting the certificate from one of your systems
- Vulnerability in SSH server (advanced attacker and/or outdated software)
- Another entry point besides SSH. Check open ports with [nmap](https://nmap.org/)

Comment: Sorry, edited my post, it wasnt clear that I use certificates authentication inkl. a private key passphrase (thats what I mean with "key-pair"). So I am not using a password, just a passphrase to unlock the private key to authenticate against the server.

Comment: Ah, I will update my answer.